# About new line and space after last row and last column respectively

Tags: python, design-patterns, newline

**What I must get as output, exactly like this :**

```
Example-1:

Input:
3

Output:
1\n
1 2\n
1 2 3

Example-2:

Input:
4

Output:
1\n
1 2\n
1 2 3\n
1 2 3 4
```

In the first example the input was 3. Hence there are 3 rows. The first row has element 1. The second row contains two elements 1 and 2 and the third row contains 1, 2 and 3 separated by a space.

```
What I actually get to: Example 1-  1 \n             Example 2 - 1 \n
the below code and I don't          1 2 \n                       1 2 \n  
want this as an output              1 2 3 \n                     1 2 3 \n
                                                                 1 2 3 4 \n
```

**There should not be any space after the each element of the last column and no new line after the last row.**

My code:

```
n = int(input())
i=1
j=1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if i>=j:
            print(j, end=" ")
        if(i!=j):
            print(end="")
    print()
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I have updated it with code; but I want the output without new line at the last row.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to have a start state and an adding state. The adding state is pre-pended with a space. Each adding state is appended to the start state in turn. When you're done with the row, append a new line character.

start state: "1"

adding state: " " + n

roll over an array from 2 to n, append the changed adding state to the current answer

append end of line character

In Javascript...

```
var start = 1
var limit = 4
for(var i = 1; i <= limit; i++){
    let retval = start;
    for (var j = 2; j <= i; j++){
    retval = retval + ' ' + j; 
  }
  if (i < limit)
      retval = retval + '\\n';
  $('<div>' + retval + '</div>').appendTo('#out');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/etLms32o/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
N = 5
result = '\n'.join(
    # space delimited numbers from 1 to current loop
    ' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, j))
    # for everything for 1..2, 1..3, 1..4 etc...
    # since range(1,1) is empty and we're starting from 2,
    # we use N+2 to ensure all loops are counted
    for j in range(2, N + 2)
)
```

Which'll give you:

```
'1\n1 2\n1 2 3\n1 2 3 4\n1 2 3 4 5'
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
lst_number= []
my_input = int(input("Enter Number:: ")) 

for i in range(0,my_input):
    for j in range(i+1):
        lst_number.append(j)
print(''.join([str(val) for val in lst_number]))
```

Comment: You can add j+1 in the code "lst_number.append(j+1)" to get required output.

Comment: It does give me the output, but in a single line without spaces. I need an exact pattern of how I already illustrated on my question.

Comment: What is the pattern you are looking? Can you comment

Comment: Please check my question, I have posted what pattern I actually want in 'block' letters.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are wondering, this is how I want my **pattern output** to be:

```
Example-1:

Input:
3

Output:
1\n
1 2\n
1 2 3

Example-2:

Input:
4

Output:
1\n
1 2\n
1 2 3\n
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It worked for me.

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(1,n+1):
    count = 1
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if j == i:
           print(count,end = "\n")
           count+=1
        else:
           print(count,end = " ")
           count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a,b=map(int,input().split())
n=0
for i in range(a):
   for j in range(b):
     n=n+1
     if(j<(b-1)):
      print(n,end =' ')
     elif(n==a*b):
       print(n,end ='')
     else:
      print(n)
```